# Invalid device ordinal error on Linux GPU server?

Tags: linux, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu

I am trying to run a tensorflow code on a GPU that I can access remotely through SSH. I am using windows CMD to SSH and then I get the Linux terminal of the server. Now I wanted to run the code on the server's GPU instead of CPU and thus I installed Tensorflow-GPU. I am using a conda environment to run python. Now, when I start python and after importing tensorflow I am getting the following error. Please help me resolve this?

```
>>> sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
2019-06-05 13:26:45.280912: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-06-05 13:26:45.309892: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 3399505000 Hz
2019-06-05 13:26:45.311731: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x55ffc55f7cc0 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-06-05 13:26:45.311780: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2019-06-05 13:26:45.315413: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2019-06-05 13:26:46.043595: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/platform_util.cc:256] unable to create StreamExecutor for CUDA:3: failed initializing StreamExecutor for CUDA device ordinal 3: Internal: failed call to cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory; total memory reported: 11719409664
2019-06-05 13:26:46.044237: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x55ffc84a7710 executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
2019-06-05 13:26:46.044297: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, Compute Capability 6.1
2019-06-05 13:26:46.044308: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (1): GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, Compute Capability 6.1
2019-06-05 13:26:46.044322: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (2): GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, Compute Capability 6.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/media/data_dump_1/group_9/anaconda3/envs/pradyumnaenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1570, in __init__
    super(Session, self).__init__(target, graph, config=config)
  File "/media/data_dump_1/group_9/anaconda3/envs/pradyumnaenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 693, in __init__
    self._session = tf_session.TF_NewSessionRef(self._graph._c_graph, opts)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Invalid device ordinal value (3). Valid range is [0, 2].
        while setting up XLA_GPU_JIT device number 3
>>> sess=tf.Session()
2019-06-05 13:27:09.128360: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:0a:00.0
2019-06-05 13:27:09.130001: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 1 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:0b:00.0
2019-06-05 13:27:09.131300: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 2 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:41:00.0
2019-06-05 13:27:09.132226: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 3 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.582
pciBusID: 0000:42:00.0
2019-06-05 13:27:09.133262: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2019-06-05 13:27:09.135097: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2019-06-05 13:27:09.385582: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2019-06-05 13:27:09.486764: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2019-06-05 13:27:09.489289: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2019-06-05 13:27:10.140611: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2019-06-05 13:27:10.145133: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2019-06-05 13:27:10.159615: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1763] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1, 2, 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/media/data_dump_1/group_9/anaconda3/envs/pradyumnaenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1570, in __init__
    super(Session, self).__init__(target, graph, config=config)
  File "/media/data_dump_1/group_9/anaconda3/envs/pradyumnaenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 693, in __init__
    self._session = tf_session.TF_NewSessionRef(self._graph._c_graph, opts)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Invalid device ordinal value (3). Valid range is [0, 2].
        while setting up XLA_GPU_JIT device number 3
>>> exit()
```

Following are the GPU details-

```
(pradyumnaenv) cse563@falcon:~$ nvidia-smi
Wed Jun  5 15:53:05 2019
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 396.54                 Driver Version: 396.54                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:0A:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   44C    P8    19W / 250W |  10791MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:0B:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 22%   53C    P8    21W / 250W |  10791MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:41:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 31%   57C    P8    22W / 250W |    677MiB / 11178MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:42:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|100%   91C    P2   132W / 250W |  11105MiB / 11176MiB |    100%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0     78117      C   python                                     10777MiB |
|    1     47128      C   python                                     10777MiB |
|    2     79606      C   ...t_nagpal/miniconda3/envs/dnn/bin/python   667MiB |
|    3     83393      C   python                                     11095MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: It seems that you are using the wrong Device number in your settings, try using a number between 0 to 2. There is also a bug associated with this error try updating your tensorflow
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23458

Comment: I don't know how to set device number. Can you please tell me how can I set that ? Also the github thread you mentioned doesn't contain any useful solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the GPU id that is being accessed is 3. However, the other GPU IDs (0 to 2) seem to be free.

You can add the following lines to make tensorflow_gpu use those GPU_BUS_IDs.

```
import os

os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0" #(or "1" or "2")
```

Comment: Thanks but the actual problem was the mismatch between the CUDA requirements of the version of TensorFlow-GPU I was using and that installed on the server. It got solved when I downgraded my TensorFlow-GPU to match the CUDA version on the server.